# Oracle NLS_DATE_FORMAT not working properly

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g

In my application I am setting the NLS_DATE_FORMAT of the session to format all dates returned by the program using the following command:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DY DDTH MON YYYY';
```

This should return the date like this: 'Fri 23rd Aug 2013'

However, if I run the following query:

```
select SYSDATE from dual;
```

I get the date in the following format: 'FRI 23 AUG 2013'. Notice the lack of the 'rd' after '23'.

If I run the following query:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'DY DDTH MON YYYY') from dual;
```

The date does come back in the desired format. So why does the 'TH' date format parameter not work when setting it through NLS_DATE_FORMAT? And are there any other date format parameters that do work when using TO_CHAR but not through NLS_DATE_FORMAT?

Thanks for your help

By the way, I am using Oracle 11.2 client and database.

## UPDATE

I was running the alter session command from within SQL Developer. I tried this in SQL PLUS and it returned the date in the correct format. However, now I am having a problem with inserting formatted dates.

If I do the following (after setting the NLS_DATE_FORMAT as above) I get a 'ORA-01861 literal does not match format string' error:

```
INSERT INTO DATE_TABLE (MY_DATE_COL) VALUES ('Thu 18th Apr 2013');
```

I would expect that to work after setting the NLS_DATE_FORMAT?

If I change the insert statement to:

```
INSERT INTO DATE_TABLE (MY_DATE_COL) VALUES ('Thu 18 Apr 2013');
```

Then it does work! Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DD DDTH MON YYYY';
```

You get an error, `ORA-01810: format code appears twice`.

If you use the same format model as your `TO_CHAR` then it works:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DY DDTH MON YYYY';

Session altered.

select SYSDATE from dual;

SYSDATE
-----------------
FRI 23RD AUG 2013
```

This works in SQL Developer and SQL*Plus.

---

For your updated question about inserting, the [datetime format documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51083) says:

> **Notes on date format element suffixes:**
>
> - When you add one of these suffixes to a datetime format element, the return value is always in English.
> - Datetime suffixes are valid only to format output. You cannot use them to insert a date into the database.

So you cannot use a string with the suffix as part of your insert, either explicitly or via the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. You would have to remove it from the string or tailor the format model to treat is as a fixed value.

Comment: Side note: if the OP didn't get this error message, his application is probably failing to do proper error checking.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo in my question. I am doing exactly what you are doing above and I am not getting the proper date format.

Comment: Thanks! I did not see that bit of the documentation. I guess the easiest solution is not to allow my users to have suffixes in the date format of my application!

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo in the alter session statment. set DY instead of DD on the first place

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DY DDTH MON YYYY';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert string literal `'Thu 18th Apr 2013'` into a column of `DATE` data type as follows(enclosing `th` in the format model with double quotes):

```
INSERT INTO DATE_TABLE (MY_DATE_COL) 
  VALUES (to_date('Thu 18th Apr 2013', 'Dy DD"th" Mon YYYY'));
```

Comment: But should I need to use the to_date function when I have already set the NLS_DATE_FORMAT? I thought that if I change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT to DY DDTH MON YYYY and try to insert a date with that format it should just work??

Comment: @user1578653 - you're using the `to_date` function implicitly anyway, effectively with the NLS_DATE_FORMAT in place of the second parameter. You just can't use the suffix during insert, it's for display only. Of course, with this model you'd need to deal with `st`, `nd`, `rd` as well as `th`, and possibly in both upper and lower case.