# pyodbc MERGE INTO error: HY000: The driver did not supply an error

Tags: python, oracle, odbc, pyodbc, python-3.9

I'm trying to execute many (~1000) MERGE INTO statements into oracledb 11.2.0.4.0(64bit) using python 3.9.2(64bit) and pyodbc 4.0.30(64bit). However, all the statements return an exception:

HY000: The driver did not supply an error

I've tried everything I can think of to solve this problem, but no luck. I tried changing code, encodings/decodings and ODBC driver from oracle home 12.1(64bit) to oracle home 19.1(64bit). I also tried using pyodbc 4.0.22 in which case the error just changed into:

<class 'pyodbc.ProgrammingError'> returned a result with an error set

Which is not any more helpful error than the first one. The issue I assume cannot be the MERGE INTO statement itself, because when I try running them directly in the database shell, it completes without issue.

Below is my code. I guess I should also mention the commands and parameters are read from stdin before being executed, and oracledb is using utf8 characterset.

```
cmds = sys.stdin.readlines()
comms = json.loads(cmds[0])
conn = pyodbc.connect(connstring)
conn.setencoding(encoding="utf-8")

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.....'""")

for comm in comms:
  params = [(None) if str(x)=='None' or str(x)=='NULL' else (x) for x in comm["params"]]
  try:
    cursor.execute(comm["sql"],params)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Edit: Another things worth mentioning for sure - this issue began after python2.7 to 3.9.2 update. The code itself didn't require any changes at all in this particular location, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've had my share of HY000 errors in the past. It almost always came down to a syntax error in the SQL query. Double check all your double and single quotes, and makes sure the query works when run independently in an SQL session to your database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried executing a few of the queries in the SQL session and they completed successfully. I copied the query and parameters directly from the error logs aswell, so the issue doesn't seem to be a syntax error. All the queries are very similar. Theyre all inserted into the same table with the same amount of parameters, always, but when executed with pyodbc, each query throws an error.

Comment: Could this be related to your problem?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398237/oracle-nls-date-format-not-working-properly

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem so. If I alter the date format in the SQL session and then run a query that throws an error from pyodbc, it will complete successfully. If I put the ALTER SESSION query inside a try catch block in Python, it doesn't even throw. It's just the MERGE INTO statemets.